# Selecting events that happen 1 hour before the predicted event

Tags: python, pandas

I'm training a binary classifier to predict whether a certain sequence of industrial log events ends up in an error or not.

For each error, I need to capture the events that happened in the hour before the error-event. I'm using a pandas DataFrame and converted the time with pd.to_datetime() so I ended up with a Year/Month/Day/Hour/Minute/Second column, which is not the index of the dataframe.

Things I tried are pulling out the corresponding hours and minutes with this code below

```
hours = data2.event_timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
minutes = data2.event_timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.minute)
```

I managed to loop over the dataset and capture a fixed amount of events, disregarding time, that happen before the error with this code:

```
dataarray = []
for index, row in data2.iterrows():
    array = np.asarray(row)
    dataarray.append(array)

listwitheventswithnoerror = []
listwitheventswitherror = []

"""-----------------------------------------------------------------"""

for index, array in enumerate(dataarray):
    if index > 50:
        if array[1] == 0: # 0 is for non-errors
            sample = dataarray[index-50:index]
            listwitheventswitherror.append(sample)

for index, array in enumerate(dataarray):
    if index > 50:
        if array[1] != 0: #non zero is for errors
            sample = dataarray[index-50:index]
            listwitheventswithnoerror.append(sample)
```

I can't seem to grasp how I can change this code to instead of taking 50 events, take the events that happen in the hour before, regarding the time column. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can convert strings (e.g. "2019-10-28T11:06:00") into a Datetime format using pandas, and you can substract two datettime objects and get a delta time.

Comment: Have you seen the [pandas.DataFrame.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) functionality?